# customize shiny checkboxinput font using css, error unused argument (style = "

Tags: css, r, colors, shiny, font-size

I am trying to change the font size and the color of my checkboxinput using inline css.

```
   library(shiny)
    shinyUI(
        navbarPage("First App",
                 tabPanel("A",
                   sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(h5("sidebar") ),
                     mainPanel(checkboxInput("add", "Add"  , style = "font-weight: 500; color: #4d3a7d;" )) )),
                 tabPanel("B") )  )
```

But I get the error `unused argument (style = "font-weight: 500; color: #4d3a7d;")`How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

You should try :

```
library(shiny)
    shinyUI(
        navbarPage("First App",
                 tabPanel("A",
                   sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(h5("sidebar") ),
                     mainPanel(checkboxInput("add", "Add"  , style = "font-weight: 500; color: #4d3a7d;" )) )),
                 tabPanel("B"),
tags$head(tags$style("#add{color: #4d3a7d;
                       font-weight: 500;
                       }"
         ))))
```

Comment: library(shiny)
shinyUI(
  navbarPage("First App",
             tabPanel("A",
                      sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(h5("sidebar") ),
                                    mainPanel(checkboxInput("add", "Add"  )) )),
             tabPanel("B")))
tags$head(tags$style("#add{color: #FFFF00;
                     font-weight: 500;
                     }"
         )) .  Is this how you said? But this doesnt change the colur :(

Comment: library(shiny) shinyUI( navbarPage("First App", tabPanel("A", sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(h5("sidebar") ), mainPanel(checkboxInput("add", "Add" )) )), tabPanel("B"), tags$head(tags$style("#add{color: #FFFF00; font-weight: 500; }" ))))

Comment: Remove "))" after tabPanel("B") and put "," then put "))))" at the end of the code. "tab$head(ta$style..." must me in shinyUI and navbarPage

Comment: I never tried it with a checkboxInput but this is how you use css code for your shiny widgets.

Comment: library(shiny) 

shinyUI( 
  navbarPage("First App", tabPanel("A", sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(h5("sidebar") )
                                                       
                                                             , mainPanel(checkboxInput("add", "Add" )) )), tabPanel("B"), tags$head(tags$style("#add{color: #FFFF00; font-weight: 500; }" ))))

Comment: But it didnt work, may be we cnt customize checkbox?

Comment: I think you can, i'm trying things then i'll tell you.

Comment: Do you want to change the backgroud color or the font color ? If backround replace "color" by "background".

Comment: font color and font size

Comment: server doesnt have anything yet, library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){})

Comment: changing to background didnt change the background color

Comment: The following code worked for me, textInputRow<-function (inputId, label, value = "") 
{
  div(style="display:inline-block; background: #FFFF00; color:#880000",
      tags$label(label, `for` = inputId),
      tags$input(id = inputId, type = "checkbox", value = value,class="input-small"))
 
}
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    textInputRow(inputId="xlimitsmin", label="x-min")
  
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
))

Comment: Well play, glad you fine !